# NSSelectorFromString does not work

Tags: objective-c

When I am using the selector, if I code like the following, everything works fine:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(placeToDownWithPos: shipSize:)]) {
    NSLog(@"respondsToSelector");
}
```

but when I tried to use the code below, the 'if statement will be false':

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"placeToDownWithPos: shipSize:");
if ([self respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    NSLog(@"respondsToSelector");
}
```

what's wrong here, and how to fix it? thanks!

Comment: Try getting rid of the space in the selector name.

Comment: @maddy thank you very much. Could you put an answer below instead of comment here, so that I can make it as the right answer and upvote.

Comment: "@rmaddy" you mean. ;)

Comment: @LeoNatan haha, you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Method names do not have spaces in them. Your code should be:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"placeToDownWithPos:shipSize:");
if ([self respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    NSLog(@"respondsToSelector");
}
```